# I want to make notification using ajax laravel when I click "Add To Chart" and the notification is Success or failed

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I want to make notification using ajax laravel when I click "Add To Cart" and the notification is Success or failed.

This is my script ajax

```
<script>
    $('#formCart').on('click','.add_cart_btn',function(event) {
      $.ajax({
          url: '{{route("add-cart", "glove-botswana-abu-m-f0a9d79f-a575-4221-bead-60ed76afd972")}}',
          type: 'GET',
          dataType: "json",
          data: $('#formCart').serialize(),
          success: function(response){
              $('#overlay').remove();
              if(response.status == "success"){
                  // $.notifyBar({ cssClass: "success", html: "Order successfully added to cart", delay: 500, animationSpeed: "fast" });
                  notification('success', 'Order successfully added to cart');
                  $('.badge').html(response.carts);
                  $('.contentCart').html(response.content);
                  removeCart();
              }else{
                  // $.notifyBar({ cssClass: "error", html: "Order failed added to cart", delay: 500, animationSpeed: "fast" });
                  notification('success', 'Order failed added to cart');
                  removeCart();
              }
          }
      });
  });
</script>
```

This my button in the blade

```
<button type="button" class=" btn btn-small btn-dark .add_cart_btn">Add to cart</button>
```

when I run this nothing change, the button haven't notification. 
what sholud I do to make notification with ajax in laravel

Comment: please be more specific about the problem you are facing. At the moment, we just know your goals :)

Comment: when I run this nothing change, the button haven't notification. what sholud I do to make notification or alert with ajax in laravel

Comment: `class=" btn btn-small btn-dark .add_cart_btn"` Wrong class name, `.add_cart_btn` should be `add_cart_btn`

Comment: This question was caused by **a problem that can no longer be reproduced** or **a simple typographical error**. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers.

Comment: nothing change when I click button

Answer (score 1):

ajax:

```
$('.add_cart_btn').on('click',function(event) {
  $.ajax({
```

button:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-small btn-dark add_cart_btn">Add to cart</button>
```

Comment: nothing to change. 
and the button `add to cart` is inside form `<form action="post" id="formCart">`

Comment: Have u try with form action="#"

Comment: & try use <script> $(document).ready(function () { xxxx_paste_ur_script_here_xxxx } );</script>